# jQuery: loop through elements and wrap in different tag

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I'm scraping content off of a public domain site (cancer.gov), and I want to reformat the markup because it's terribly formatted in a table. I have jQuery at my disposal, and I'm just trying to put it into the console so I can copy it and paste it into Vim.

I've gotten as far as making an array of the `td` elements I want to make into `h3`'s, but when I try to loop over them and wrap them in `h3` tags, I get `Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`, which I believe is that a DOM element isn't found, which makes no sense.

Check out my commented [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/M4Pn5/).

Bonus points: The `td`'s are all questions, and the only way I could think of to split them into array indices was to split them on the `?`, which cut out the question mark in the output. What's the best way to put them back in?

#### Update

If you want to check out the page and try things in the console, it's [here](http://www.cancer.gov/cancertopics/coping/chemotherapy-and-you/page2).

Comment: You are working with strings. A simple console.log(this) would show you the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but I need them in an array. How would `console.log(this)` work, based on my fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a jQuery object does not magically turn them into DOM elements.

---

Just create on big string of HTML, and pass that to the jQuery constructor:

```
var questions = $('selector here...').text().split('?');

questions = $('<h3>' + questions.join('?</h3><h3>') + '?<h3>' );
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Pn5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply grab the content into an array and then do whatever you want with the array without the worry of the question mark.

```
var myarr = $('#Table1').find('tr:even');//even to exclude the hr rows
```

here I show some things you can do with that:

```
var myQuest = myarr.find('td:eq(0)').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
});//questions
var myAns = myarr.find('td:eq(1)').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
});// answers

//process the arrays:
for (var i = 0; i < myQuest.length; i++) {
    alert(myQuest[i]+ myAns[i]);
};

myarr.find('td:eq(0)').wrap('<h3>');//wrap the questions
```